# How would I find the decision line for two 2d gaussian plots with unequal covariancematrix?

Tags: matlab

I am plotting 2 multivariate gaussians in MATLAB, and my decision line as a result will be parabolic in shape, which I can see by looking at the contour or surf of the data. However, I need a way to quantify the pparabola that represents the decisionline. Taking the local minima seems like a good idea, but I dont know if that is possible for a contour plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decision line is where difference of two gaussian function becomes zero.

so using fcontour from symbolic toolbox:

```
syms x y
mu_x = 10;
mu_y = 10;
mu_x1 = 60;
mu_y1 = 10;
sigma = 20;
sigma1 = 30;

f = 1/(2*pi*sigma^2) * exp(-(x-mu_x)^2+(y-mu_y)^2)/(2*sigma^2)...
  -( 1/(2*pi*sigma1^2) * exp(-(x-mu_x1)^2+(y-mu_y1)^2)/(2*sigma1^2));
fcontour(f ,'LevelList', [0])
```

but I do not have tested